# String with quotation marks from SpringMVC controller, not shown with javascript-jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, database, string, spring-mvc

I try to show data with jquery, sent from a controller of Spring MVC. The problem is the string have quotation marks from database, therefore, my code with javascript - jquery, not working.

For example, my string is (principal:"Carl Duvierts") in database, sending by the controller.

```
alert("${person.name}"); //not working
```

Comment: have you tried using single quotes? e.g. `alert('${person.name}');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the object you're using is already a string, you don't need the quotes around it in an alert.

```
//this will work
var stringWithQuotes = 'abc"de"fg';
alert(stringWithQuotes);//no quotation marks inside the parentheses

//The code you provided:
alert("${person.name}");
//will just alert the actual string '${person.name}', not what is referenced by the variable
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I'm newbie in javascript.